# Space of continuous functions with compact support dense in space of integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

There are a few exercises in my script and I have no idea how to proof this one. I would like to see a proof for this, but I can‘t find one.

> We call the space of continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R} ^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with compact support $C_{0}\left( \mathbb{R} ^{n}\right)$, and the space of integrable functions $f:\mathbb{R} ^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ $L^{1}\left( \mathbb{R} ^{n}\right)$.
>   Show, that $C_{0}\left( \mathbb{R} ^{n}\right)$ is dense in $L^{1}\left( \mathbb{R} ^{n}\right)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a smooth function $g$ with the properties $$g(x)=1, |x| \leq 1$$ $$g(x)=0, |x| \geq 2$$ $$0 \leq g \leq 1$$

Then take $g_t(x)=\frac{1}{t^n}g(\frac{x}{t}),t>0$

Also  we have that $f_m:=f 1_{\{|x| \leq m\}} \to^{m \to +\infty} f$  in  $L^1$ thus if 
 $\epsilon >0 $ exists $M \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $\int|f_M-f|<\epsilon$

Then  take $f_M \ast g_t$.

You can prove that $f_M \ast g_t$ is continuous ans that $||f_M \ast g_t -f_M||_1 \to^{t \to 0^+} 0$

Clearly $f_M \ast g_t$ have compact support and $''\ast''$ denotes the convolution.

Comment: $f \ast g_t$ has no reason to have compact support. Take $t = n = 1$ for simplicity and fix an $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(x) > 0$ for every $x$. Then $f(x)g(x-y) > 0$ for $x \in [y-1,y+1]$ and hence for arbitrary $y$, $f \ast g(y) \geq \int_{y-1}^{y+1} f(x)g(x-y) dx > 0$.

Comment: @RhysSteele  you are right..i edited my answer..thank you for the correction.

Comment: $g\in C^{\infty }$, right? Im not a native english speaker and im not sure, if smooth function means what i think it means.

Comment: @Moe1234 yes smooth means $C^{\infty}$